# Cant disable some particular options in a dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I want to disable some particular options in my second dropdown i.e. `id = "event"` based on selection of the first dropdown list `id="domain"` . 
What I tried to do in here is that if I select Robotics from first dropdown menu then in the 2nd drop down menu options with class name `B`,`C`, `F`, `G` will be disabled.
 Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name = "myform">
Domain Name: &nbsp; <select name="domaindrop" id="domain">
                                <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
                                <option value="Robotics" selected="selected">Robotics</option>
                                <option value="Coding">Coding</option>
                                <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
                                <option value="General Events">General</option>

                            </select><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="CHECK EVENT LIST" onclick ="validate()">

        Event Name: &nbsp; <select name="eventdrop" id = "event">
                                <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
                                <option class="A" value="A">A</option>
                                <option class="B" value="B">B</option>
                                <option class="C" value="C">C</option>
                                <option class="D" value="D">D</option>
                                <option class="E" value="E">E</option>
                                <option class="F" value="F">F</option>
                                <option class="G" value="G">G</option>
                                <option class="H" value="H">H</option>

                            </select><br><br>


    </form>

    <script >

        function validate(){
        if (document.myform.domaindrop.value == "") {

        document.myForm.domaindrop.focus();
        }
        else if(document.myform.domaindrop.value == "Robotics")
        {
            $('B').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('C').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('F').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('G').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
}

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

No action is performed by this code.Please help me into this.

Comment: don't forgot "." for class selector

Comment: Same output . Nothing

Comment: For styling with CSS use classes. For controlling an element with external code such as JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, etc. use the ID-attribute.

Access Class-elements with "." and ID-elements with "#".

Comment: Thats doesn't change the output..

Answer (score 1):

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tiarhai/pen/MqaZxd) of explanation below.

---

You have a few problems, one that seems to be over looked here is:

`<input type="submit" ...`

A `submit` button inside a form automatically submits the form (refreshes / changes the page). That is resetting all your dropdown and select values. Change it to:

`<input type="button" ...`

Secondly as mentioned previously, remove classes from your select options, and instead we will use jQuery to select them using their actual values:

```
<select name="eventdrop" id="event">
    <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
```

And now for your jQuery, you had the right idea, but were simply selecting the domain name dropdown wrong:

```
function validate()
{
    var domainDropValue = $("#domain").val();

    if (domainDropValue === "")
    {
        $("#domain").focus();
    }
    else if(domainDropValue === "Robotics")
    {
        $('#event option[value=B]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#event option[value=C]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#event option[value=F]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#event option[value=G]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.` before the class name. It should be `.B`, `.c` and so on for class selector:

```
$('.B').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('.C').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('.F').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('.G').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: No change in output. Those options are still enabled

Answer (score 0):

You are submiting form directly with submit button.
add : `e.preventDefault()` for prevent submit.
Then some code in full jquery :

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#domain").val() == "") {

  } else if ($("#domain").val() == "Robotics") {
    $('.B, .C, .F, .G').attr("disabled","disabled");
  }
 })
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/673259/

Comment: sorry. still those options are enabled. I have used an on click function there. Hope its no mess there.

Comment: @ArunavaSaha you can check my jsfiddle, option are disabled. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/673259/

Comment: Yes it worked .Thank You . there was a silly probem with my jquery file linked.:3